# Javascript and JQuery array issue

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I have a WCF project that has data being pushed to a javascript/jquery front end but the problem I am having is I am trying to use the data to insert each field into a Google Map.  Even though there is only one record from a list from C#, in the array, it displays the record multiple times when I try to see the data by an alert box.  What am I doing wrong?  Please find my code below:

```
function onSuccess(result) {
    var DArray = new Array();
    var data = result;

    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        alert(DArray.push(result));
        // alert(data.LocId);
        //document.getElementById("locid").value = data.LocId;
        //alert(data.Title);
        //alert(data.Loc);
        //alert(data.Lat);
        //alert(data.Long);
        // alert(data.length);

    });


    function onFail() {
        document.getElementById("locid").value = "Error";
        document.getElementById("title").value = "Error";
        document.getElementById("loc").value = "Error";
        document.getElementById("lat").value = "Error";
        document.getElementById("long").value = "Error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you define your `onFail` function inside the `onSuccess` function? Please indent it properly

Comment: Please show us either the value of the `result` parameter or how those functions are invoked

Comment: you're pushing the same result for the length of the array

Comment: Should it be `DArray.push(item)`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have duplicates because you're pushing the same result for every item in you're data array.

```
var result = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var DArray = new Array();
var data = result;


$.each(data, function (index, item) {
        alert(DArray.push(result));
});

// DArray would be [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You push `result` which is an Array, every time, when you should be pushing `item`

```
var DArray = new Array();
var data = result;

$.each(data, function (index, item) {
        alert(DArray.push(item));
});
```

Or alternatively,

```
DArray[index] = item
```